# Cannot Control-Drag into ViewController.swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, controls, drag

I am trying to control-drag objects in the storyboard into the ViewController.swift, but nothing is working. I have tried sliders, buttons, switches, pickers, everything. I need to finish this app quickly, so please help!

Answer (score 7):

You probably didn't set your view controller class in your Utility inspector.

When you are on your Storyboard, select your view controller, open the Utility inspector (right panel) and set the related class (which is `ViewController` in your case). This way, you'll be able to `ctrl + drag`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you create your new file to inherit UIViewController, it should be a CocoaTouch Class and not a swift class. then you can drag from your Main.storyboard to the new View Controller.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem. This is what I noticed if you are trying to drag drop into the storyboard with **ctrl** button pressed the drag drop does not work. Just click drag and drop from the touchpad.
I guess this should help.